# Hide master page content in pages which are using it at design mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio

My maser page is broken and thus when trying to design my pages which are inheriting master page is shown ugly and non-editable.

Is there a way to hide master page content in design mode so I can continue to editing my pages without trouble for dealing with master page content ?

There must be a way to disable it.. Maybe some extension ?

Comment: @techdo This is NOT duplicate.. I'm looking for a design time solution.

Comment: What type of control to be disabled?

Comment: @techdo It doesn't matter but the control I'm looking for is `Panel`. I can bound it with a div or any other control.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the control using:

```
style="display:none"
```

in the `style` tag.

Comment: This works fine in design time but the same applies to run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an option to hide the master page content in design view. Not even VS 2012 has that option.